# Adjust entries in Google Sheet for short orders

Tags: javascript, performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am relatively new to scripting. My programming experience stems from a QBASIC course when I was 11, and teaching myself HTML when I was a teenager (a while ago).

This script resides on what is essentially a log of orders for a company. Occasionally, orders will be "shorted" if all the products are not ready in time for shipment. For these cases, I decided to write a script that would update various case quantities and dollar amounts.

The script below is working, but updating the values is very, very slow.

The main function is "ShortMaker" but the top function "GetByName" is used to reference column headings -- I have to add columns when new products are added to our lineup, so using hard column references means I would have to change my code every time we added a new product and this was the best function I could find in my online searches. This may be the part that's slowing it down, though. Not sure. (Is there a way to tell?) Note that there *are* instances of hard column references. I have yet to update these to the new system.

````
function getByName(colName, row) 
{  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var data = sheets[1].getRange('DL1:'+sheets[1].getLastColumn()+'2').getValues(); // Get top 2 rows 
  var col = data[0].indexOf(colName);
  if (col != -1) {
    return data[row-1][col];
  }
}

function ShortMaker()
{    
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  ss.setActiveSheet(ss.getSheets()[1]);  // Get Flash Report
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange("A"+":"+"I"+lastRow);  
  var rows = range.getValues();    

  // Enter SO#
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','Enter SO#',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {    
    var SONum = (response.getResponseText());        
  } 
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){return}    

  // Enter # of products shorted
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','How many products were shorted?',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {    
    var CODEqty = (response.getResponseText());        
  } 
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){return}  

  var PCodes = [];
  var QtyCodes = [];

  //Enter Codes & Qtys
  for (var i = 0; i < CODEqty; ++i)
  {
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();          
    var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','Enter Product Code ',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) 
    {    
      PCodes[i] = (response.getResponseText());          
    } 
    else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){return}    

    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();        
    var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','Enter Qty Shorted for Product Code '+PCodes[i],ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK)
    {    
      QtyCodes[i] = (response.getResponseText());                   
    }        
  }

  // Enter New Invoice Amount
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','Enter New Invoice Amount',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {    
    var Invoice = (response.getResponseText());        
  } 
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){return}    

  // Enter New Discount Amount
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();  
  var response = ui.prompt('Adjust Order for Short','Enter New Discount Amount',ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {    
    var Discount = (response.getResponseText());        
  } 
  else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL){return}  

  // INSERT VALUES ONTO FLASH REPORT  

  // ************ Edit 'var range' Column when columns are added ****************  

  var lastRow = sheets[1].getLastRow();
  var range = sheets[1].getRange("A6"+":"+"EC"+lastRow);  
  var rows = range.getValues();  

  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i)    
  {    
    var row = rows[i];     
    if (row[7]==SONum)
    {
      sheets[1].getRange('S'+(i+6)).setValue("SHORTED"); // Mark order Shorted
      var OriginalInvoice = sheets[1].getRange('AC'+(i+6)).getValue(); // Get original invoice amount      
      sheets[1].getRange('EB'+(i+6)).setValue(OriginalInvoice); // Enter original invoice amount in short section     
      sheets[1].getRange('AC'+(i+6)).setValue(Invoice); // Enter new invoice amount      
      sheets[1].getRange('AA'+(i+6)).setValue(Discount); // Enter new discount amount
      for (var u = 0; u < CODEqty; ++u)
      {
        var Pcol = getByName('LSC'+u, 2);
        var Qcol = getByName('LSQ'+u, 2);
        sheets[1].getRange(Pcol+(i+6)).setValue(PCodes[u]); // Enter Product Code
        sheets[1].getRange(Qcol+(i+6)).setValue(QtyCodes[u]); // Enter Qty Shorted
      }
    }
  }
}

```
````